# Tuning MySQL On Azure Windows Server Setup

Tags: mysql, database-tuning, performance, performance-tuning

I have a MySQL 5.5 running on Azure VM Windows Server 2012. Once per second the log db gets about 2K inserts through LOAD DATA INFILE... once a day I need to run stats and when the stats are crunching through the data, which involves creating tables to a 'tmp' database, the LOAD DATA INFILE times out. I'm already using disk striping to help with the write load, also the tmp database for stats is saved on a different disk but the timeouts are still occuring.

I should also mention the LOAD DATA INFILE is executed by another service which has a timeout of 60 seconds and which I have no control over other than starting and stopping it.

I have also tried including LOW_PRIORITY on all of the INSERT queries executed by the stats, but still no luck.